# Setting loglevel in Quarkus

Tags: logging, categories, quarkus, levels

I want to run with :

`quarkus.log.level=DEBUG`

And set spesific pacage to other level using catecory, like this:

`quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus".level=WARN`

This works after the augmentation phase is finished, but not during the augmentation phase, where the loglevel remains on DEBUG for "io.quarkus"

Is there is a way to change this, thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying figure out?

Comment: I’m trying to figure out how to set the log.level to WARN on io.quarkus packages and have a general log.level set to DEBUG. 
I’am using this properties in application.properties 
`quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus".level=WARN`

This works after the  augmentation phase is finished , but not during the augmentation phase

Answer (score 0):

When you set the log level to below DEBUG, you must also adjust the minimum log level. This setting is either global, using the quarkus.log.min-level configuration property, or per category:

quarkus.log.category."org.hibernate".min-level=TRACE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).